# Django - allauth: How to keep only the allauth login url

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

How can I remove the allauth signup URL while keeping the login URL in Django? I am using the allauth package for authentication and I would like to only keep the login URL while removing the rest URLs as i have project that needs only the login. Can anyone provide a code snippet on how to achieve this?

I have tried using the url method to exclude the rest urls from my URL patterns, but that also broke the login URL. I was expecting to only remove the signup URL while keeping the login URL accessible through allauth package in Django

edit: my urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns = [path('', include('Departments.urls')),
           path('', include('Managements.urls')),
           path('', include('Registration.urls')),
           path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),]
```

Comment: Can you paste your URL pattern code here?

Comment: sure i added them to the post but i followed allauth tutorial

Comment: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/urls.py

i think something like this work try this let me know
from allauth.account.views import LoginView
url(r'^/login/', LoginView.as_view(), name="login" ),

and delete the part which u included allauth.urls in your code

Comment: You can register the single route that you want without registering everything from the package. Look at `allauth.urls` code to see how the package authors do this.

Comment: i tried that but now that broke the login URL

Comment: Then you should provide more detail in your question.

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is include the views from the allauth libary:

```
from allauth.account.views import signup, login, logout
urlpatterns = [
    path("account/login/", login, name="account_login"),
    path("account/logout/", logout, name="account_logout")
]
```